# Python | Error al enviar email con python desde formulario html

Tags: python

Error al enviar email con python desde formulario html.

**Archivo** contactar.html

```
<form action="main.py" method="get" id="contact_form" class="contact_form clearfix">
    <input type="text" class="contact_input" placeholder="Nombre" required="required" name="nombre">
    <input type="email" class="contact_input" placeholder="E-mail" required="required" name="email">
    <input type="text" class="contact_input" placeholder="Tema" required="required" name="tema">
    <textarea class="contact_input contact_textarea" placeholder="Texto" required="required" name="texto"></textarea>
    <button class="contact_button">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

**Archivo** main.py

```
import os
import smtplib
import cgi

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
nombre =  form.getvalue('nombre')
email =  form.getvalue('email')
tema =  form.getvalue('tema')
texto =  form.getvalue('texto')

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
import smtplib 

remitente = email 
destinatario = "miemail@gmail.com" 
asunto = tema 
mensaje = texto

email = """From: %s 
To: %s 
MIME-Version: 1.0 
Content-type: text/html 
Subject: %s 

%s
""" % (remitente, destinatario, asunto, mensaje) 
try: 
    smtp = smtplib.SMTP('localhost') 
    smtp.sendmail(remitente, destinatario, email) 
    print "Correo enviado" 
except: 
    print """Error: el mensaje no pudo enviarse. 
    Compruebe que sendmail se encuentra instalado en su sistema"""
```

Comment: Es difícil de decir ya que estás capturando cualquier error sin especificar ningún tipo de excepción, lo cual ya es una mala práctica en sí mismo. Intenta especificar por lo menos el `Exception` y debuggea el error.

Comment: ¿estás ejecutando un servidor web?, ¿estás en linux o windows? hace falta mas información para poder ayudar. `action="main.py"` me hace pensar que estás abriendo *contactar.html* directamente con *file:///*, y en ese caso no es posible ejecutar *CGIs*